# Authentication with oauth/openid in integration tests

Tags: spring-security, authorization, openid, keycloak

I have the following situation locally:

- a spring boot application secured with spring security and openid
  The application is configured to make use of the authorization code flow.
- a keycloak server against which I can authenticate

Now I want to write some integrations tests, and I am a bit blocked.

By default, my security is configured to be stateful (so I get a session id cookie if I navigate to my application and not an access token), which is not an issue as I have kind of an API gateway.
And I have the following:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
    http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)
            .addFilterAfter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(benutzerRepository), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()));
}  // @formatter:on
```

And my application.properties is similar to:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=application_name
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=36a2740b-e7b9-4e66-9e2f-242a19d7815f
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-name=Keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid, roles
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/application_name/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/application_name/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/application_name/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/application_name/protocol/openid-connect/certs
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
```

This works but now, I want to write some integration tests. So basically calling the API from my spring boot application in a test to trigger some operations, and my API is of course protected.

So what I did is whith a WebClient to try to get an access token just for the sake of my integration tests, repeating the requests which normally are "magically done" in the background.

My idea was to:
- call with webclient the authorization url to get a code
- send this code with the client id and the client secret to get a token

Sounds easy but I am just blocked.I keep getting error=invalid_request from KEycloak and I have no idea why.

I am just trying to do the following just a start to get the code (which is probably wrong...):

```
URIBuilder authorizationURI = new URIBuilder("http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/application_name/protocol/openid-connect/auth");
        authorizationURI.addParameter("client_id", "application_name");
        authorizationURI.addParameter("scope", "openid");
        authorizationURI.addParameter("state", "123456");
        authorizationURI.addParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/keycloak");
        authorizationURI.addParameter("response_type", "code");
        WebClient webclient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(authorizationURI.toString())
                .build();
        var test = webclient.post()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .body(
                        BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", "user")
                                .with("password", "password"))
                .exchange()
                .block()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same issue, I found how to fix it.

So one has to set confidential for its client in Keycloak and then enable service clients. Then it is possible to do as following:

```
URIBuilder authorizationURI = new URIBuilder("http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/application_name/protocol/openid-connect/token");
        WebClient webclient = WebClient.builder().build();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        formData.put("grant_type", Collections.singletonList("client_credentials"));
        formData.put("client_id", Collections.singletonList("application_name"));
        formData.put("client_secret", Collections.singletonList("tralala-5d0e-4bea-938b-884c1ce4c981"));
```

And tadaaaa, you get an access token for your tests.